# Instantiate subclass from superclass Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I want to try and instantiate a Child object that extends Parent with the properties of a previously instantiated parent object. So something like this:

```
class Parent {
    ClassName property1;

    // Setters and getters
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public Child(Parent parent) {
        this.property1 = parent.getProperty1();
        // + other properties
    }
}

Parent parent = new Parent();
parent.setProperty1(prop);

Child object = (Child)parent; // Casting exception
Child object2 = new Child(parent); // This is not ideal
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like the builder pattern might be of use...

Comment: I think you cant downcast it to child

Comment: Why would you do this.property1 = parent.getProperty1();? If you create a child and you have a public method in your parent, you can access all your parents properties through the child (since the child *is-a* parent)

Comment: I want to pass a parent to the constructor so I can set the values that are already set in parent to child.

Comment: Why do you consider `Child object2 = new Child(parent)` not ideal? Do you have a strong reason for the parent to exist before the child does?

Comment: @VancertStaff That means that you are creating a copy constructor, where you take a Child object and you create a new Child object from its parent's values. Child object2 = new Child(parent); does exactly this.

Comment: Because if a new property is added to Parent, child will have to be modified as well. Wouldn't that be less flexible?

Comment: @VancertStaff: Unforunately you cant copy properties dynamically

Comment: Right. Okay. I'm gonna leave the question up for a bit longer, see if anyone knows any other way. If no answer is given, I'll stick with Child object2 = new Child(parent);

Comment: you can override the method `getProperty1()` from Child to call `parent.getProperty1()`, this way, each time you call `getProperty1` from `Child`, the property from `parent` will be returned

Comment: I'd have to have a Parent parent; property inside of Child if I was to do that.

Comment: @Pphoenix: Of course you can copy properties dynamically, there's [Apache BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) that does it. However in this case it's overkill, like bringing a neutron bomb in a street fight...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First look up polymorphism. It seems you're not familiar with one of the main features of an OOP language.

Second, you need to instantiate your parent like this

`Parent p = new Child();`

`Child c = (Child) p;`

Comment: It's true. I'm not very experienced with all of the OOP features, since I use mainly inheritance to solve my problems. I'm doing some research on polymorphism right now. Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: No problem, just try to go through a tutorial (there are an infinite amount of those to find on the internet), then hopefully you'll understand what you can do with an OOP language. ;-)

Comment: Right, I've read a bit about interfaces and, althought I solved my problem in another way, this response is totally correct for the question asked. Thanks for the help